# Prove that $\lim_{x\mathop\to a}x^n=a^n$

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{x\mathop\to a}x^n=a^n$$

Is there an easy and rigorous way to show this using epsilons/deltas or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't completely avoid the epsilons and the deltas- but there is a quick proof as follows:

1) Show that if $f(x)=x$ then $lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=a$

2) Show that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous functions, then so is $f_1 \cdot f_2$

3) Use induction.

Comment: Your point (1) is missing the assumption that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @JackM: $f(x)=x$ is cont. Here one has to use epsilon delta argument :).

Comment: Oh sorry, for some reason I interpeted $f(x)=x$ as $f(a)=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a+h$. We then need to prove that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} (a+h)^n = a^n$$
Let $n > 0$ and $h>0$ to begin with. We then have for sufficiently small $h$
$$a^n < (a+h)^n < a^n+2nh a^{n-1}$$
Now let $h \to 0$ and conclude using sandwich theorem. Repeat the same argument for $h < 0$. For $n < 0$, set $m = -n$ and conclude what you want.